# Maven Iterator but Focus on one item

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

So I have a unique problem based on a more-complicated-than-it-needs-to-be environment that is out of my control.

I have been tasked to create a Maven application whose sole purpose is to take the files found under the resources directory and compile them into a zip file while filtering environment specific values into the copied file. Easy enough. I replicated the vendor's build process based on the little information I was allowed to have since they have a proprietary system.

Now what I'd like to do it focus in on a particular item in this iteration and only build that item. My issue is I'm not using profiles at this time and was trying to find a way to use what I have to complete this action.

Here is a simple mock up of my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.im.special</groupId>
    <artifactId>So-Special</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>iterator</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <itemsWithProperties>
                                <itemWithProperty>
                                    <name>DEV</name>
                                    <properties>
                                        <prop.one>Some</prop.one>
                                        <prop.two>Unique</prop.two>
                                        <prop.eh>Values</prop.eh>                                        
                                    </properties>
                                </itemWithProperty>
                                <itemWithProperty>
                                    <name>DEV2</name>
                                    <properties>
                                        <prop.one>More</prop.one>
                                        <prop.two>Unique</prop.two>
                                        <prop.eh>Values</prop.eh>                                        
                                    </properties>
                                </itemWithProperty>
                            </itemsWithProperties>
                            <pluginExecutors>
                                <pluginExecutor>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                                    </plugin>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <descriptors>
                                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                        </descriptors>
                                    </configuration>
                                </pluginExecutor>
                            </pluginExecutors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Let's assume I have way more items specified than the two here and those items have more properties than I have defined as well. The current assembly plugin produces exactly what I need; one compilation of resources for each item with properties with the appropriate filtered files and it's beautiful.

Now, the wrench. How would I go about or is it even possible to run this build structured the way it is for only one of the items in the defined list. My example scenario is this:

- I'm processing the list items for their relative environments and
  then deploy those compiled items to the appropriate environment.
- I am then asked to regenerate a compiled artifact for DEV because someone
  deleted the file because; why not.
- I now need to change my workspace to my latest tag and run the
  process for one item based on time constraints and priority. Running all would
  take to long and I have SLAs to meet.

I know if I was using profiles my pom would be different and I could simply `mvn clean package -PDEV` and go about my day. Unfortunately that's not my build process and I am looking to see if I need to create a completely different process in case my request is not viable.

Also; not having so many env.properties files is nice because all my maintenance is in the pom.xml and not across multiple files.

Comment: First can you make a full example what you have and explain in detail what you like to achieve... (best on Github or alike?)... Also you could take a look at https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin ? Maybe I misunderstand the post here...

Comment: I'll read up on the multienv plugin before I make a full example but I would have figured the maintainer of the plugin would be able to respond on the capabilities of that plugin? I thought my description was fairly good (could have been better, sure) and my request pretty simple in nature.I have a list of items. A, B, C. I run `mvn package` and get a list of output A.zip, B.zip and C.zip. I just wanted to know if I could put something else in the mvn command such as `mvn package itemsWithProperties:A` for one off use cases and just get A.zip?

Comment: At the moment it does not support such thing because it should be kept simple not too much configuration options etc. (Maintainer it's me ;-))

Comment: Okay, I appreciate the feedback. The iterator seems to be more flexible than the multienv plugin for my purposes. For now then I'll just continue using the iterator plugin as-is and manage my output files manually.

Comment: @khmarbaise if you would not mind placing your last comment as the answer, I'm good flagging that as such since the plugin does not support my unique requirement.